# Error "specified module could not found"

Tags: python, module, liblas

I just installed the Liblas with pip:

```
C:\Users\Geri>pip install liblas
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): liblas in c:\python27\arcgis10.2\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python27\arcgis10.2\lib\site-packages (from liblas)
```

when I want to import the module, I got the following:

```
>>> import liblas
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\liblas\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core import get_version
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\liblas\core.py", line 136, in <module>
    las = ctypes.CDLL(lib_name)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Please help

Comment: Do you have a standard Python installation or a third-party distribution such as OSGeo4W or Anaconda? Pip installs it to the correct location for a standard install.

Comment: I use the 2.7 version of python which is installed with ArcGIS

Comment: If it was installed with ArcGIS, perhaps it created a different site-packages path other than the standard one for packages being imported into their software, or perhaps the environment variables were not set correctly for system path

Comment: I also installed the laspy module, which works perfectly.

Comment: [looks like you're not the only one running into this conflict/problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26479532/)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is no answer there either :(

Comment: Did you install the liblas binary librarie (the DLL, I presume it is)? Can it be found? Because liblas is looking for something (sadly, it doesn't exactly show what: `self._name`...), loading it through ctypes, which is the interface to functions in binary libraries.

Comment: I simply used 'pip install liblas' in the cmd, so I don't really know where should I look it for

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to ensure that `liblas.dll` and `liblas_c.dll` were in the DLLs folder in all my python instances (I have python 2.7 in ArcGIS, OSGeo4W and WinPython).

I found the dll's in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs` after trying every method I could find for installing the liblas package (WinPython control panel, pip and installing using the exe from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libLAS/1.6.0).

I have not tried using `liblas` via OSGeo4w as I am not sure where to put the dlls (I put them in the `C:/OSgeo4w64/bin` folder but that did not help) and OSgeo4w command_line package list in the installer tells me that liblas is not available. I also ensured that `C:/OSgeo4w64/bin` is in my path (as that was a suggestion above and elsewhere)... not sure if that helped.

All working fine now.